# What is the purpose of using /bin/date shell in Centos?

Tags: linux, centos

Can you give me an example of any real world scenario for changing login shell to an application? What is the purpose of using /bin/date shell in Centos?

Comment: ... So that someone can ssh in and only that application will run.

Comment: Every shell is a program. Have you checked if some user is actually using this as shell? There are services like time and daytime, which provide date over the network (see (x)inetd services), maybe a way to provide this is by having a user with /bin/data as login shell.